# opencart category parent Undefined variable: entry_parent

Tags: opencart

Im really stressing out on this one, unable to get a fix. Just installed opencart in a sub-folder/ sub-directory and wordpress in the root. Got everything to run fine, currently sharing the same DB. I know its not wise, however im testing. I hit a problem when editing categories, no matter what i try i cannot remove this error when trying to add a category parent under

- admin panel->catalog->categories-> data

you should see a nested dropdown table. However instead im greeted with a terrible error in place of this much needed function. Please could somebody assist thats preferably an opencart guru or php whiz.

Here is my error message: 
Notice: Undefined variable: entry_parent in /var/www/vhosts/domain.com/httpdocs/store/admin/view/template/catalog/category_form.tpl on line 54

Comment: What version are you on?

Comment: Hi Jay

I'm on the latest version. I just just installed a fresh copy from the site. So it should be the latest release. Really hope you can help. I'm unable to work without the fix. 

From your experience how stable is opencart? Should I be using another cart?

Kind regards

Comment: Can You provide us with at least demo account and URL to Your administration?

Comment: Hi shady. Thank you for being so kind to offer. However I found the solution. The new version of opencart category.php file is corrupted. I had to installed the previous version (opencart) of the category.php  file by replacing it on FTP. Worked and fixed the error. Will set resolved.